# Change Button And Text After Button Pressed

Tags: html

I am trying to make a text-based (With ASCII art) RPG game and I am having trouble with the opening sequences. Here's my script for the opening:

```
<body>
<pre>
Welcome To __________! <!-- No name yet :P -->


<button onclick="menuButtonPressed1()" type="button">Cool, is this the whole game?</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function menuButtonPressed1() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No, there's more!";
}
</script>


</pre>
</body>
```

This code works fine for getting the button to show the text and all, but what I want to do is make it so that the button clears the current text on screen and changes the button to a different text. For example, what I want is that it says something, but when I press the button it will change the text and the button's text will change too. So if you see: (Ignore the color)

```
Welcome to ____!

(There will be button here with text "Cool, is this the whole game?")
```

and you press it you'll clear all the current text on screen and get only: (Again, ignore the color)

```
Hello to you!

(There is another button here with different text)
```

If there is something I could add to this to make it easier to understand or easier to answer etc. please tell me so I can correct it. I'm not very good with html yet, so if I might have gotten something completely wrong in my code, I'm sure you can understand.

Comment: can you put your code in  a fiddle and post the link here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should wrap the text in some tag like <p> or <span>. Then give it an ID and use that ID at onClick of button to change that text along with button text.
It just use the same code with different ID.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this to make it clearer?

Comment: Oh, wait, I got it! Thanks a lot! :D